# Feedback on my demo reel

Tags: demo-reel, sound-design, critique

Hey guys I'm still new to the field of sound design and just finished up my demo reel. I was seeing if I could get some feedback on it. http://vimeo.com/20907263
Thanks!

Comment: My first impression was good, but effects at the start and coda are good but "more" then graphics. Some sounds are lost but it covered by music and looks good but sounds like music clip where sound design is not main thing. http://socialsounddesign.com/questions/147/hmm-demo-reel-yeah-right very good advise about length and purpose of demo.

Comment: @Evgeni Unfortunately I lost the session to the first clip and couldn't take out the music. As for the effects at the beginning and end I was trying to spice up the animation since there's not much going on there. Do you think any of the clips were too long and needed to be shortened?

Comment: Its pretty good considering the fact your new to sound designing (so am I btw lol), but just wondering what SFX Libraries are you using they sound great. 

Answer (score 1):

it need to decide what is the purpose of this reel then it helps you to decide what part to take out. For example you want to show game producer that you can make good shoots and war athmosphere or film producer how you work with narration. Trailers it different thing than sound design of whole picture of game. In movie and games they should see that you keep attention on every detail. Trailers especially for movies it short advertising they have 10-20 sec on the TV 30 sec on radio mostly and it's also story but very short it has begining-progress-end. I suggest you to leave EA game but give it more complete form, movie "colonial kitchen" if you have moment how narration is changing ( maybe they leave this restaurant and go to pub:), and work a little bit more on animation, it little bit scretchy on my point of view, maybe it could be soft. and write what is your job exactly in all these cuts.